# jQuery .each() how to use on this object

Tags: jquery, each

I getting some JSON and trying to do an `.each` on the response.  I'm unsure how to do that on this object. I'm trying to get the Title and SysID.

[image]

Here is my JS:

```
        var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;;
    $.ajax({
        url: siteURL + "/content/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('topsupportarticles')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.d.results.length > 0) {
            console.log(response);
                    //This section can be used to iterate through data and show it on screen .each should be here
                    console.log(response.d.results[0].Title);
                    $(".js-top-support").html("<li><a href=\"/pages/snDetails.aspx?articleID=KB0010606&sysID=" + response.d.results[0].SysID + 
                    "\" class=\"js-top-support-articles\">" + response.d.results[0].Title + "</a><div class=\"x-editable-menu\"><span class=\"btn-edit\"><span class=\"icon-wrench\"></span></span></div></li>");
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Error: " + response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: that's not an array. you cannot do that

Comment: Did you try `for(var i = 0; i < response.d.results.length; i++) { console.log(response.d.results[i].Title) }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose one of these two things.

1. You can use `JSON.parse()` method to parse the string as valid json.
2. Use `dataType:"json"` which can parse the json string as a valid json *automatically*.

---

To me second approach is better. So, you can do this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: siteURL + "/content/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('topsupportarticles')/items",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  },
  dataType:"json", //<------------------------ ADDED DATATYPE HERE
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.d.results.length > 0) {
      console.log(response);
      //This section can be used to iterate through data and show it on screen .each should be here
      console.log(response.d.results[0].Title);
      $(".js-top-support").html("<li><a href=\"/pages/snDetails.aspx?articleID=KB0010606&sysID=" + response.d.results[0].SysID +
        "\" class=\"js-top-support-articles\">" + response.d.results[0].Title + "</a><div class=\"x-editable-menu\"><span class=\"btn-edit\"><span class=\"icon-wrench\"></span></span></div></li>");
    }
  },
  error: function(response) {
    alert("Error: " + response);
  }
});
```

But you should note if you have only one object there then you can use `response.d.results[0]` in here, otherwise use a `for` loop or `$.each()` to iterate over the objects in the array.

---

As a side note you have two semicolons here:

```
var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you upload your code on jsfiddle or codepen.

Try this :

```
var results = response.d.results;

jQuery.each(results, function(key,value) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);
    var sysid = value.SysId;
    var title = value.Title;
});
```